# Get size of a file that is uploaded on dropbox

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to get the size of a file that is uploaded on **dropbox**.
I tried this:

```
@ECHO OFF
color A
for %%A in (https://www.dropbox.com/s/e9q3ssvhitsatbq/Update.zip) do set Size=%%~zA
echo %Size%
pause
```

But it doesn't work.
The output has to be in bytes.
So I want the batch file to output (for example) 1024 B
Is there a way to get the size of the file that is uploaded on **dropbox**?
Anybody?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible in Windows batch as it is. Either use win32 builds of `wget`...

```
wget -S --spider --no-check-certificate https://www.dropbox.com/s/e9q3ssvhitsatbq/Update.zip
```

...or `curl`...

```
curl -I https://www.dropbox.com/s/e9q3ssvhitsatbq/Update.zip
```

...and parse the output. Note that both these commands perform a `HEAD` request, i.e. they lookup the file on the server without actually downloading it.

There's probably a way to do it in powershell, but that is beyond my knowledge.

**Update 1:** How to save the size to a variable?

```
@ECHO OFF
SET URL=https://www.dropbox.com/s/e9q3ssvhitsatbq/Update.zip
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%A IN (`wget -S --spider --no-check-certificate %URL% 2^>^&1 ^| FINDSTR "Content-Length: "`) DO (
    SET SIZE=%%A
)
ECHO %SIZE:~16%
```

Output:

```
142515188
```

**Update 2:** Is there a way to make it faster?

I don't think so. It takes about 10 seconds on my end. If I open the URL in my browser, it also takes about 10 seconds until I get to the actual download page. Dropbox seems kinda slow.

On a sidenote, opening the URL causes a `302` redirection, so that actually *two requests* are send, which explains one half of the 10 seconds.

Comment: and is it possible to save the value to a variable(if I do it through the wget)?

Comment: You need authentification to access the file size !

Comment: and how can I do that? :D --no-check-certificate??

Comment: @Tom Lenc: This is needed due to `https`, yes. Updated accordingly.

Comment: but is there a way to make it more faster?

Comment: @TomLenc: Please see update. Besides, if you want to do me a favor, you may upvote my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the [DROPBOX API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#metadata) with a POST/GET method.
You can use VBS to do it.

Comment: "You have to" might be a slight exaggeration.